# External CSS style sheet NOT working.

Tags: html, stylesheet

```
<head>
 <title>
  My Site
 </title>
 <style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
 </style>
</head>
```

I cannot figure out how to fix it. My page comes up completely unaffected by the style sheet.

Answer (score 6):

The `link` should not be placed within the `style` tag. Correct example:

```
<head>
 <title>
  My Site
 </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<head>
    <title>
        My Site
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
</head>
```

Do not use style when you want to link external style  sheets,
Use style only when you have to write the CSS in the HTML document itself.

For more info : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp